# SAN Storage Array in Hyper-V 2012R2 Failover Cluster - outdated file table info?

Tags: windows-server-2012, failovercluster, cluster-shared-volumes

We have Dell MD3600f **SAN storage array** and **two HP servers** for VM failover clustering solution.

MD3600f is set, disks are mapped and connected to Hyper-V servers. On Hyper-V's I have partitioned and formatted  these disks (**NTFS**) and assigned drive letters (**N**, **Q**, **S**) on both servers using DISKPART.

Now I can create folders or files on this disks using CMD with no problem. But if I delete folder (`"rd s:\test"` for example) on Server One and then list folders on Server Two (`"dir s:\"`) it shows me the very "test" folder I deleted from Server One, i.e. **Server Two is unaware of changes I made on using Server One and vice versa.**

How can I tell Hyper-V treat this disks differently? Or what should I do to make these disks (N, Q, S) valid shared disk for Failover Cluster?

Comment: It appears that you're doing it wrong. You can't create standard NTFS volumes on these disks and attach each server to them. You need to be using a clustered file system, such as a CSV provides. You need to create a Cluster Shared Volume from these disks.

Comment: Perhaps you are rigth. As I can see now, this filesystem can and will be created automatically if during Test-Cluster cmdlet it finds out that both servers could see same storage. I'm not aware is it required or not format shared volume to NTFS before cluster creation: in my case I did it and seems fine now.